# WinError 10013 when I use pip for installing any package

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install packages on my Python environment on Windows and every time when I do

```
pip install pacakgename
```

I get this error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016FFD3F9748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/name/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016FFD3F9550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/name/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016FFD3F9588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/name/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016FFD3F94A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/name/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016FFD3F9390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/name/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement name (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for name
```

Even for a not valid name I get this error. I tried using proxies, but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Disable any proxy or VPN if you are using one
2. Give access to pip/python through your firewall

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to your operating system. It is because of your security software. I had Kaspersky Total Security and this problem happened for me.

To solve this problem, try to disable your antivirus or try to disable only the application firewall from the security software's settings.

Also, you can give access to just pip by searching through the security application's settings.

And about proxies, you can use them or not. They are not important in installing packages.

Comment: Why this should happen?

Comment: Because some antivirus software uses user rating for blocking connections. And `pip` has very low rating and I do not why it has low rating! But try it, I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any third-party firewall applications like Simplewall, then make sure that python.exe has permission to access internet.

I had the same problem after I uninstalled Simplewall because it left filters enabled, so I had to install it again then it worked.